# $this variable and variable scope in Object Oriented PHP

Tags: php, oop, scope

I am trying to write a class and I run into two errors.

```
class Foo {

    protected $count;

    function __construct() {
        $this->count = sizeof($_POST['some_key']);
    }

    static function get_count() {
        echo $this->count; // Problem Line
    }
}

$bar = new Foo;
$bar->get_count(); // Problem Call
```

The problem call is on the last line. using $this in the line with the "// Problem Line" comment generates a "Using $this when not in object context" error. Using "self::count" in place of "this->count" generates an "Undefined class constant error." What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_count` is static. Static methods belong to the class, not the instance. As such, in a static method call, there *is no* `this`. Similarly, you can't reference concrete member variables (such as `count`) from within a static method.

In your example, I don't really understand why the `static` keyword is used (since all you're doing is echoing a member variable). Remove it.

Comment: Thanks. In the case of using self in the original question, would the variable "count" have to declared as static as well?

Comment: PHP is not my strong suit but I would assume so given that it makes no conceptual sense to access an instance variable from a static method.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try playing around with it to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to do the following:

```
class Foo {

    protected $count;

    function __construct($some_post) {
        $this->count = sizeof($some_post);
    }

    function get_count() {
        echo $this->count;
    }
}

$some_post = $_POST['some_key'];
$bar = new Foo;
$bar->get_count($some_post);
```

OR:

```
class Foo {

    protected $count;

    function __construct() {
        global $_POST;
        $this->count = sizeof($_POST['some_key']);
    }

    function get_count() {
        echo $this->count;
    }
}

$bar = new Foo;
$bar->get_count();
```

Comment: Thanks. This saves a lot of problems with $_POST and is generally cleaner and more maintainable.